# Spring boot Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

For 500 users concurrent request and save there data,
We are having 3 or 4 error  users about 'Unable to acquire JDBC Connection' only for 500 users concurrently.

Is there a way to fix this?. since if we test again still same for 500 users concurrently having 3 or 4 error

Have update the maximumPoolSize 10 to 20 then add minimumIdle,idleTimeout,connectionTimeout,leakDetectionThreshold but still same.

hikari properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=50000
spring.datasource.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold=60000
```

Hikari log

```
Timeout failure stats (total=20, active=20, idle=0, waiting=179)
```

Error message

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause
```

Comment: 20 connections for 500 users is probably to low. I would also decrease the connection timeout (you don't want to wait 50seconds before you get an error). If you don't get leaks detected (at least make sure you don't leak connections check if you are messing around with Connections yourself). Increase the max poolside to start with.

Comment: @M.Deinum is `maximumPoolSize=50` enough for 500 users?

Comment: 2 connections can be enough for 500 users - it all depends on what those users are doing and how your application is configured. If you are setup to actively hold a connection for a transaction (Spring does this excessively IMO), and hold onto that transaction for long periods and even for read-only operations, then it won't be enough. What will be though is something you'll have to figure out from performance tuning your application. Most don't want to go with a 1:1 ratio as that is quite a bit, so you'll balance the time your users can spend waiting for a connection to figure it out

Comment: As mentioned how many connections you need, depends on your usecase. The only way to determine that is to measure and make sure you don't have any connection leaks.